# How can I extract keywords from a Python format string?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I want to provide automatic string formatting in an API such that:

```
my_api("path/to/{self.category}/{self.name}", ...)
```

can be replaced with the values of attributes called out in the formatting string.

---

How do I extract the keyword arguments from a Python format string:

```
"non-keyword {keyword1} {{escaped brackets}} {} {keyword2}" => 'keyword1', 'keyword2'
```

Comment: I guess you don't want to use format?

Comment: @user189 I **will** use `<str>.format(**kwargs)`. My question is about building that `kwargs` dictionary automatically.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use the [`string.Formatter()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter) to parse out the fields in a string, with the [`Formatter.parse()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse):

```
from string import Formatter

fieldnames = [fname for _, fname, _, _ in Formatter().parse(yourstring) if fname]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from string import Formatter
>>> yourstring = "path/to/{self.category}/{self.name}"
>>> [fname for _, fname, _, _ in Formatter().parse(yourstring) if fname]
['self.category', 'self.name']
>>> yourstring = "non-keyword {keyword1} {{escaped brackets}} {} {keyword2}"
>>> [fname for _, fname, _, _ in Formatter().parse(yourstring) if fname]
['keyword1', 'keyword2']
```

You can parse those field names further; for that you can use the `str._formatter_field_name_split()` method (Python 2) / `_string.formatter_field_name_split()` function (Python 3) (this internal implementation detail is not otherwise exposed; [`Formatter.get_field()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.get_field) uses it internally). This function returns the *first part* of the name, the one that'd be looked up on in the arguments passed to `str.format()`, plus a generator for the rest of the field.

The generator yields `(is_attribute, name)` tuples; `is_attribute` is true if the next name is to be treated as an attribute, false if it is an item to look up with `obj[name]`:

```
try:
    # Python 3
    from _string import formatter_field_name_split
except ImportError:
    formatter_field_name_split = str._formatter_field_name_split
from string import Formatter

field_references = {formatter_field_name_split(fname)[0]
 for _, fname, _, _ in Formatter().parse(yourstring) if fname}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from string import Formatter
>>> from _string import formatter_field_name_split
>>> yourstring = "path/to/{self.category}/{self.name}"
>>> {formatter_field_name_split(fname)[0]
...  for _, fname, _, _ in Formatter().parse(yourstring) if fname}
{'self'}
```

Take into account that this function is part of the internal implementation details of the `Formatter()` class and can be changed or removed from Python without notice, and may not even be available in other Python implementations.

Comment: Just curious, Martijn, would *you* use a simple str.replace() or re.sub() (or something entirely different) to generate the new string?

Comment: @mtik00: depends on the use case; sometimes a `str.replace()` is just what is called for.

Comment: Thanks for your input!  In this specific case, I would have used `str.replace()` in a loop; nice and simple.

Comment: @mtik00: this is not a simple replace job however; the `str.format()` format allows for *nested* placeholders too, for example.

Comment: When does the parse() function return a None as field? I'm not able to understand the documentation :(

Comment: @Moberg: `None` is output when there are `{{` or `}}` escape braces, because at that point the parser stops to emit information but there is only a literal text value, there's no field to name or provide formatting info or a conversion function for.

Comment: Great answer! my humble contribution - if you want to prevent field-name duplicates, do use the python `set` syntax like so: `{fname for _, fname, _, _ in Formatter().parse(yourstring) if fname}`

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong: no, there isn't.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE:** _formatter_parser() is a private method and hence **not available** anymore for **python >= 3.8** or even earlier

Building off Martijn's answer, an easier format for the comprehensive list that I've used is:

```
>>> yourstring = "path/to/{self.category}/{self.name}"
>>> [x[1] for x in yourstring._formatter_parser() if x[1]]
['self.category', 'self.name']
```

It's functionally exactly the same, just much easier to digest.

Comment: I can't find any documentation for `_formatter_parser()`! is it an alias for `Formatter.parse()`?

Comment: It may as well be afaik, here is the relevant section for `Formatter.parse()` https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2085bd0877e17ad4d98a4586d5eabb6faecbb190/Lib/string.py#L260-L261, as well as the relevant section for `_formatter_parser()` itself: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c4cacc8c5eab50db8da3140353596f38a01115ca/Objects/stringlib/unicode_format.h#L1100-L1128

Comment: As of Python 3.11.2, `_formatter_parser()` is not longer a method of str.  You can replace it with `Formatter().parse(yourstring)`.

Comment: `_formatter_parser()` also not available for python `3.8.8` -> `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_formatter_parser'`

Answer (score 3):

If all placeholders are named, a special dictionary could be used to intercept which keys are tried to be accessed and logged to an array.

```
def format_keys(str_):
    class HelperDict(dict):
        def __init__(self):
            self._keys = []
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            self._keys.append(key)    
    d = HelperDict()
    str_.format_map(d)
    return d._keys
```

Note that if there are unnamed placeholders, an IndexError will be raised by `.format()` (tuple index out of range).

Comment: A fun idea but it needs some polish.  e.g. the `None` returned by `__getitem__` will cause unhandled exception from a format string like `'My {foo} is {bar:03d}'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `"path/to/{self.category}/{self.name}".format(self=self)`. You could thus work with those kwargs in `__getattr__`.

Comment: I don't think this will actually.

Comment: You don't think this will actually what?

Comment: @JaceBrowning: it'll work; `self.__getattr__` will be called for each attribute on `self`. However, this doesn't help for anything that isn't an attribute on `self`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the clarification. This answer is almost exactly what I need, but I expect there will be non-attribute keywords as well.