# How to pass string format as a variable to an f-string

Tags: python, string, f-string

I am using f-strings, and I need to define a format that depends upon a variable.

```
def display_pattern(n):
    temp = ''
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        temp = f'{i:>3}' + temp
        print(temp)
```

If it is relevant, the output of `display_pattern(5)` is:

```
  1
  2  1
  3  2  1
  4  3  2  1
  5  4  3  2  1
```

I wonder if it is possible to manipulate the format `>3`, and pass a variable instead. For example, I have tried the following:

```
def display_pattern(n):
    spacing = 4
    format_string = f'>{spacing}' # this is '>4'
    temp = ''
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        temp = f'{i:format_string}' + temp
        print(temp)
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyramid.py", line 15, in <module>
    display_pattern(8)
  File "pyramid.py", line 9, in display_pattern
    temp = f'{i:format_string}' + temp
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

Is there any way I can make this code work? The main point is being able to control the spacing using a variable to determine the amount of padding.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

you should to put the `format_string` as variable

```
temp = f'{i:{format_string}}' + temp
```

the next code after `:` is not parsed as variable until you clearly indicate.
And thank @timpietzcker for the link to the docs: [formatted-string-literals](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals)

Comment: You can nest variables up to one level: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals

Comment: yes but the next code after `:` is not parsed as variable until you clearly indicate.

Comment: @bearbrown, thanks for providing a detailed explanation. This solves all my doubts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the alignment and padding tokens separate from each other:

```
def display_pattern(n):
    padding = 4
    align = ">"
    temp = ''
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        temp = f'{i:{align}{padding}}' + temp
        print(temp)
```

EDIT:

I think this isn't quite correct. I've done some testing and the following works as well:

```
def display_pattern(n):
    align = ">4"
    temp = ''
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        temp = f'{i:{align}}' + temp
        print(temp)
```

So I can't really say why your method wouldn't work...

Comment: why putting a nested `{}` works in this case? I mean `{align}` and `{padding}` are inside `{}`.

Comment: i think you should not to delete your post it helped me to find the solution.