# How do you format user input as an f-string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to input variables names and have them converted to actual variables, similar to what you can do with print statements. Is this possibe?

```
print(f'I love {fruit} and the colour {colour}')
```

Code:

```
fruit=apples
colour=red

message=input('Enter your message: ')
print(message)
```

Desired input:

```
Enter your message: I love {fruit} and the colour {colour}
```

Desired Output:

```
I love apples and the colour red
```

> Solution: [How can i use f-string with a variable, not with a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351740/)

```
variables = {
    'fruit': 'apples',
    'colour': 'red'
}

message=input('Enter your message: ').format(**variables)
print(message)
```

Input: `I love {fruit} and the colour {colour}`

Output: `I love apples and the colour red`

Comment: @Thierry  that's not the right dupe

Comment: @MadPhysicist The more I read the question, the less I'm sure about what the OP wants, actually... Do you have a better duplicate in mind?

Comment: @Thierry. OP wants to format user input as an f-string. They forgot to put quotes around the right hand side of the first two assignments, before the input, but I don't think that's important.

Answer (score 1):

```
fruit = "apples"
colour = "red"

message = input('Enter your message: ')
words = [i for i in message.split()]
variables = [i[1:-1] for i in words if i[0] == '{' and i[-1] == '}']
for i in variables:
    if i == 'fruit':
        words[words.index('{fruit}')] = fruit
    if i == "colour":
        words[words.index('{colour}')] = colour

print(' '.join(words))
```

> **Input**

```
Enter your message: I love {fruit} and the colour {colour}
```

> **Output**

```
I love apples and the colour red
```

Comment: You could have `str.format` do all that for you...