# Replace word in string using f-string

Tags: python, string, syntax

In Python, I'm trying to insert a variable into an imported string that already contains the variable name - as pythonically as possible.

Import:

```
x = "this is {replace}`s mess"
```

Goal:

```
y = add_name("Ben", x)
```

Is there a way to use f-string and lambda to accomplish this?  Or do I need to write a function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497625/how-to-postpone-defer-the-evaluation-of-f-strings and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351740/how-can-i-use-f-string-with-a-variable-not-with-a-string-literal

Comment: You can do it without f-strings: `x.format(replace="Ben")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better option to achieve this will be using `str.format` as:

```
>>> x = "this is {replace}`s mess"
>>> x.format(replace="Ben")
'this is Ben`s mess'
```

However if it is must for you to use f-string, then:

1. Declare `"Ben"` to variable named `replace`, and
2. Declare `x` with *f-string syntax*

Note: Step 1 must be before Step 2 in order to make it work. For example:

```
>>> replace = "Ben" 
>>> x = f"this is {replace}`s mess"
      # ^ for making it f-string

>>> x
'this is Ben`s mess'   # {replace} is replaced with "Ben"
```