# How can I use f string to call a list index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dataframe, f-string

I've read [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351740/how-can-i-use-f-string-with-a-variable-not-with-a-string-literal), but it didn't work here. I've a dataframe and want to add new column with the month index considering the position they've in a list.

I don't want to create an if condition because I've more languages in real life. That's why I want to use f string to call my list. But it isn't working.

Here is the example:

```
dic_events = {'month':['January', 'February'], 'url':['www.abc.com', 'www.def.com']}

df_events = pd.DataFrame(dic_events)

def add_month_index(language, month):
  month_en = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
  month_de = ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"]
  df_events['month_id'] = f"month_{language}".index(f"{month}") + 1
  return df_events

add_month_index('en', 'January')
```

Comment: What's the goal here? Please show expected output.

Comment: A better approach would be to have a dictionary holding your languages - `months = {'en': [...], 'de': [...]}`, then use `months[language]` to choose one of the lists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: @Jab the expected output is to have a column called 'month_id' in which we should see 1 when the row is related to January. And 2 when it's related to February...

Comment: @0x5453 no, we're creating a new column to the dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary that maps the language to the list of month names.

```
def add_month_index(language, month):
  months = {
      "en": ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
      "de": ["Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"]
  }
  df_events['month_id'] = months[language].index(month) + 1
  return df_events
```

I'm not sure why `month` is a parameter to the function. It seems like you would actually want to get that from the `month` column of the df, so each row of the table will get the month ID corresponding to its month, rather than assigning the same month ID to every row.