# inserting a variable into an fstring using .replace()

Tags: python, f-string

I have a code something similar to bellow.

```
name = 'Dave'
message = f'<name> is a really great guy!'
message = message.replace('<name>', '{name}')
print(message)
```

the variables are a little more complicated than this, and a user (who may not be programming literate) will have entered  into a variable via input().  I'm wanting to convert  to {name} so fstring can handle the variable.

The expected output would be "Dave is a really great guy!".  instead, its outputting "{name} is a really great guy!".  Is there a way I can handle an issue like this?

Comment: `message.replace('<name>', name)`…!?

Comment: Why not have `message = f"{name} is a really great guy!"` and change the variable `name` into something else?

Comment: This is XY problem. Fix your f-string literal.

Comment: whats inside the {} or <> are not relevant.  a non-programming literate person will have entered the message string, and I'm wanting to change their variable marked in <> to be a functional fstring using the more complicated variable they will not have used

Comment: Try:  
name = 'Dave'  
message = f'{name} is a really great guy!'  
print(message)

Comment: So basically you ask how/is it possible to take user input with placeholder, that will be processed as being f-string? That's not clear from your current question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use f-string with a variable, not with a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54351740/how-can-i-use-f-string-with-a-variable-not-with-a-string-literal)

Comment: that is correct.  I am trying to replace the placeholder with an actual variable.  the variables are more complicated than just {name}, I was simplifying it, apparently too simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confused about f-strings. An f-string interpolates variables *right there in that literal*. Consider f-strings as syntactic sugar over the `+` operator:

```
message = f'{name} is a really great guy!'
message = name + ' is a really great guy!'
```

These two lines are equivalent for the purposes of this example. It takes the value of the `name` variable and bakes it into the string, then assigns the result to `message`. **The result is a regular plain string.** There's nothing "f-stringy" about `message` anymore, it's just the string `'Dave is a really great guy!'`.

If you put some curly braces into the string afterwards, it will not be retroactively evaluated as an f-string replacement.

```
message = '<name> is a really great guy!'
message = message.replace('<name>', '{name}')
```

This is equivalent to what you're doing. Of course it will only replace "<name>" with "{name}". Literally like that.

Since you're doing replacement anyway, there's no point in using f-strings here. Just replace the placeholder `<name>` with the variable value:

```
message = '<name> is a really great guy!'
message = message.replace('<name>', name)
```

Comment: ah I see, since its not in ' ', it becomes the variable.  that was much simpler than I apparently was making it out to be

Comment: Yes. You _could_ do `.replace(..., f'{name}')`, but that's just a complicated way of writing `name`. But `'{name}'` just literally means "{name}".