# python f-strings with path parameters within fastapi path

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, f-string

I'm wondering if you can use f strings within a path in fastapi. For example, I want to do the following:

```
common_path = '/{user}/{item_id}'

@app.get(f'{common_path}/testing')
```

would this work?

Comment: Have you tried…?

Comment: All you need to do is play around with strings in the Python interpreter. If it produces the same string that you’d write manually (which it does), then yes, it’ll work.

Comment: You’ll need to make `common_path` an f-string too, *and* `user` and `item_id` need to already be defined at the time you initialize `common_path`.  Given those conditions it should work fine.

Comment: @Samwise Not if the string is supposed to literally contain “{user}”!

Comment: Maybe this’ll help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75256747/476

Comment: i want `user` and `item_id` to be interpreted as path parameters in the fastapi app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's work as intended!

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
common_path = '/{user}/{item_id}'
@app.get(f'{common_path}/testing')
def read_commom_path(user: int, item_id: int):
    return {"user": user, "item_id": item_id}
```

And running uvicorn as `uvicorn fastApiTest:app --reload --host localhost --port 1999`

And below is the result from testing using Postman
[image: Postman]