# Trigger f-string parse on python string in variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, string-formatting, f-string

This question comes from handling `jupyter magics`, but can be expressed in a more simple way. Given a string `s = "the key is {d['key']}"` and a dictionary `d = {'key': 'val'}`, we want to parse the string.

The old method would be `.format()`, which will raise an error - it doesn't handle dictionary keys.

```
"the key is {d['key']}".format(d=d)  # ERROR
```

I thought the only way around was to transform the dictionary to an object (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404665/accessing-elements-of-python-dictionary-by-index) or here).

```
"the key is {d.key}".format(obj(d))
```

But [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) explained nicely that you can simply leave out the quotes to get it working:

```
"the key is {d[key]}".format(d=d)
```

Still the new method `f'string'` does handle dictionary keys ain an intuitive python manner:

```
f"the key is {d['key']}"
```

It also handles functions - something `.format` also cannot handle.

```
f"this means {d['key'].lower()}"
```

Although we now know that you **can** do it with `.format`, I am still wondering about the original question: given `s` and `d`, how do you force a `f'string'` parse of `s`? I added another example with a function inside the curly brackets, that `.format` can also not handle and `f'string'` would be able to solve.

**Is there some function `.fstring()` or method available? What does Python use internally?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

String formatting can handle most string dictionary keys *just fine*, but you need to remove the quotes:

```
"the key is {d[key]}".format(d=d)
```

Demo:

```
>>> d = {'key': 'val'}
>>> "the key is {d[key]}".format(d=d)
'the key is val'
```

`str.format()` syntax isn't quite the same thing as Python expression syntax (which is what f-strings mostly support).

From the [*Format String Syntax* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

> ```
> field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
> [...]
> element_index     ::=  digit+ | index_string
> index_string      ::=  <any source character except "]"> +
> ```

and

> [A]n expression of the form `'[index]'` does an index lookup using `__getitem__()`

The syntax is limited, in that it will convert any digit-only strings into an integer, and everything else is always interpreted as a string (though you could use nested `{}` placeholders to dynamically interpolate a key value from another variable).

If you *must* support arbitrary expressions, the same way that f-strings do and you **do not take template strings from untrusted sources** (this part is important), then you could [parse out the field name components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996937/how-can-i-extract-keywords-from-a-python-format-string/25997051#25997051) and then use the [`eval()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to evaluate the values before you then output the final string:

```
from string import Formatter

_conversions = {'a': ascii, 'r': repr, 's': str}

def evaluate_template_expressions(template, globals_=None):
    if globals_ is None:
        globals_ = globals()
    result = []
    parts = Formatter().parse(template)
    for literal_text, field_name, format_spec, conversion in parts:
        if literal_text:
            result.append(literal_text)
        if not field_name:
            continue
        value = eval(field_name, globals_)
        if conversion:
            value = _conversions[conversion](value)
        if format_spec:
            value = format(value, format_spec)
        result.append(value)
    return ''.join(result)
```

Now the quotes are accepted:

```
>>> s = "the key is {d['key']}"
>>> d = {'key': 'val'}
>>> evaluate_template_expressions(s)
'the key is val'
```

Essentially, you can do the same with `eval(f'f{s!r}', globals())`, but the above might give you some more control over what expressions you might want to support.

Comment: Thanks :) Still hoping for an actual solution, but didn't know about this!

Comment: @Roelant: made that part of my answer now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How do we do `Formatter().parse(template)` for a template string that was a triple-quote f-string?

Comment: @HappyFace: not sure what you mean. Both *f-string* and *triple-quoted* are just differences in *syntax* to produce a string *value*, you can produce the same value with different syntax too. All `Formatter().parse()` cares about is a string *value*, not how you produced the value. However, any `{...}` placeholder syntax you used in an f-string are *already filled in*, because that's what that syntax does; execute the expressions to fill the placeholder slots *immediately*. There is no template to extract from that.

Answer (score 0):

> [G]iven `s` and `d`, how do you force a `f'string'` parse of `s`? Is there some function or method available?

This can be done... using `eval`. [**But beware `eval`!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

```
>>> eval('f' + repr(s))
the key is val
```

The `repr` is there to escape any quotes and to wrap `s` itself with quotes.

If you are aware of which variables to format (`d` in this case), opt for [Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55457601/10239789) of doing `str.format`. The above solution should be your last resort due to the dangers of `eval`.

Comment: Thanks :) I was aware of `eval` but indeed am trying to avoid it.